# Sending self is not working

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Not sure on what to make title please edit if needed.  I have a procedure

```
procedure TFZone1Mod7.ChangeText(sender: TObject);
var
  ShapeOrderNo: integer;
  FoundComponent: TComponent;
begin
  if TryStrToInt(copy(TShape(Sender).Name,6,MaxInt),ShapeOrderNo) then
    begin
      FoundComponent := FindComponent('label'+inttostr(ShapeOrderNo+12));
      if (FoundComponent is TLabel) then
            Label25.Caption := TLabel(FoundComponent).Caption
      else
          showmessage('not found');
    end;
  showmessage(TShape(sender).Name);

end;
```

so i call the procedure on a Shape1MouseEnter.  So i would think (Self) would send shape1 but it dont it sends the form(TFZone1Mod7)  How i can get it to send the shape?
here  is how i am calling it.

```
procedure TFZone1Mod7.Shape1MouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
    changetext(self);
end;
```

Comment: You mention `Self` in your question, but there is no `Self` in your code. Please show how `Self` is involved.

Comment: sorry pasted thw wrong snip at the end. now fixed.

Comment: Your final code should read `ChangeText(Sender)` as `Sender` is the `TShape` for which the `OnMouseEnter` event fired the `Shape1MouseEnter` method. You might even consider `ChangeText(Sender as TShape)` just in case you hook the `Shape1MouseEnter` method to an `OnMouseEnter` of a control that is not a `TShape`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside this method

```
procedure TFZone1Mod7.Shape1MouseEnter
```

`Self` is an object of type `TFZone1Mod7`. And that's your form. Remember that `Self` refers to the instance associated with the active method. And in your code, the class is a form and so the instance, `Self`, is always a form instance.

To know what `Self` is, look at the type that follows the `procedure` or `function` keyword. The `Self` instance is an instance of that type.

In your situation, if you want to pass the shape you can pass either `Shape1`, or to be more general, `Sender`. The latter allows you to share one event handler between multiple shapes.

This sort of mistake highlights why you should use checked casts with the `as` operator. When you make a mistake, you will get informed of it immediately and in a helpful way. Your unchecked casts just lead to hard to understand cryptic errors.

So I'd probably be inclined to declare `ChangeText` as receiving a parameter of type `TShape`. And then calling it like this:

```
ChangeText(Sender as TShape);
```

And this allows you to remove the casts from `ChangeText` and confine them just to the event handlers which by necessity only have a `TObject` instance, `Sender`, available.

Comment: Great response. Thanks for the help!

Comment: And Glen, if you're ever in doubt about what gets sent as tsuch a generic TObject parameter, set a breakpoint at the beginning of the handler, and inspect Self.ClassName